# ES Query select highest matching "should" field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Say I have this ES data

```json
{
      {
        "_source": {
          "type": "mammal",
          "title": "Fast cat",
          "body": "Fast cat"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "type": "mammal",
          "title": "Fast doggg",
          "body": "Fast doggg"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "type": "mammal",
          "title": "Fast dog",
          "body": "Fast dog"
        }
      }
}
```

Now I have this query, in which the `source` is static and I simply attach params.

GET animals/_search/template

```json
{
  "source": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "type": {
                "query": "{{type}}"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "should": [
          {
            "match": {
              "title": {
                "query": "{{animal}}",
                "fuzziness": 2
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match_phrase_prefix": {
              "body": "{{personality}}"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "params": {
    "animal": "dog",
    "personality": "fast",
    "type": "mammal"
  }
}
```

The above will return the first three results.

How to match only the highest scoring `should` ("Fast dog")?

Comment: do u need only first hit from  the result?. If thats the case you can just pick first record

Comment: I don't want first result. If multiple results have the same number of matches, I want those results to be returned instead.

Comment: There is no option in Elasticsearch to do it. It needs to be handled in client side. You have document scores in response they can be used to get only top docs from response